# CakePHP: Multiple links to same model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Lets say each book has AuthorA and AuthorB fields.
Both fields are foreign keys for `authors` table.

table authors with fields: id | name

table books with fields: id | name | a_author_id | b_author_id |

How should controller, model and view be set up to be able to create a book with dropdown list of "author a" and "author b" both coming from author table? How would form-input for author-a (and author-b)  look like inside "Add" view for Book model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup 2 belongsTo association in your `Book` model with different aliases for `Author` model.

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'AAuthor' => array(
        'className' => 'Author',
        'foreignKey' => 'a_author_id'
    ),
    'BAuthor' => array(
        'className' => 'Author',
        'foreignKey' => 'b_author_id'
    )
);
```

Use `$this->Book->AAuthor->find('list')` to get the authors list and set the array to view and specify same array using `'options'` key in `Form->input()` options for both `a_author_id` and `b_author_id` fields.

Comment: If Books can have multiple authors (not limited to a fixed amount), it's also possible to use a `HasAndBelongsToMany` relation. You'll have to change the database design to achieve this and things may be a bit more complicated when sorting/filtering books etc.